# SPSE only just works on iPad

Tags: support

From home I often use my iPad to check for moderation issues and answer questions, but have found that the interface really works very poorly on iPad - especially code view where I can't see more than the first few lines and have no scroll bars to see the rest.

Are there any plans to get this fixed any time soon?

Comment: My understanding (without having an iPad to refer to) is that two-finger scrolling in code view should work even without scroll bars displaying. My colleagues have seen the same behaviour in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> especially code view where I can't see more than the first few lines and have no scroll bars to see the rest.

Just use two-finger scroll to scroll in the iPad and iPhone.